# Cpp: Accessing an object in a function without passing it to the function or declaring it global

Tags: c++, object

Hello I am very new to object oriented programming and want to know if there is a way to access members of an object of a class inside a function without passing the object to the function and without declaring it as a global variable.

The reason for the question is that I am working with some legacy code and in a very nested function I need to use an object that is not passed through all of these functions. I don't want to change all these functions and also I don't want to declare a global variable so is there a better way? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is there some other object which is already being passed through all the functions, that you could add a pointer-field to, and set that pointer to point to your object before calling the top-most function?

Comment: "I want a deeply nested call to have access to variables outside its local scope and arguments" is a global, and those are generally best avoided, but if this is what you need to do, so be it. You can often make a *singleton* class in C++ that helps to contain the mess here, as at least that's lightly namespaced.

Comment: Personally I'd refactor the code so it made sense for that object to be available in that function. Yeah it might be a bit of work but in the long run most likely worth it. The problem with a global or singleton is what happens when you want to use a different object in that function? What do you do when you find the next function that needs something like this? Add another global? Another singleton?

Comment: In the end you DO have to pass the object (by reference) or references to the member variables. Adding any kind of global variables will make the code harder to maintain (since anybody else can get access to the global variable to and start changing its content.... and yes in any big enough project this will happen at some point and break the code unexpectedly

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I would opt for a reference since the object must be passed in